# Android Studio recommends adding android:layout_alignLeft property but it breaks layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

My layout code below, using `android:layout_alignStart`, was working flawlessly in Eclipse. However, recently I switched to the official Android Studio. When I use the alignStart property there, Android Studio underlines it with a wavy red line and says "To support older versions than API 17(project specifies 9) you should also add android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview1".

However, I tried replacing it as recommended by Android Studio, and I do not get the output alignStart was supposed to give! I am trying to place `dataView2` to the right of `textView2`, but it currently lies on top of `textView2`...

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/dataView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dataView1"
    android:layout_alignBelow="@+id/dataView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/planet_mass_label" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your original code uses `layout_alignStart="@+id/dataView1"`, the line you should add for pre-API 17 compatibility is

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/dataView1"
```

not

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
```

The final code should be

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/dataView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dataView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/dataView1"
    android:layout_alignBelow="@+id/dataView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/planet_mass_label" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently your minSdk is 9, so you're getting that red line which says "To support older versions than API 17(project specifies 9) you should also add android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview1".

Refer this link: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

If you want your minSdk to be 9 or less than 17, than you should use both, `android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/dataView1"`

`android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dataView1"`

accordingly.